# drag and drop with multiple sortable options in bbc glow

Tags: drag-and-drop, jquery-ui-sortable, glow

Is it possible to drag and drop the child div inside the parent.Below code it is possible to drag and drop through out the col1,col2,col3. I would like to drag the child divisions with in that column itself. eg: if Column Col1 contain child A,B,C and the divsions inside the A should be sortable through out A.

```
 new glow.widgets.Sortable(
    '#cols-example .col1, #cols-example .col2, #cols-example .col3',
    {
            draggableOptions : {
                    handle : 'strong'
            }
    }
);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
new glow.widgets.Sortable(
'#cols-example .col1, #cols-example .col2, #cols-example .col3',
{
        draggableOptions : {
                handle : 'strong'
        }
}
);

  new glow.widgets.Sortable(
  '#A .maincat',
   {
       constrainDragTo : '#A',
       axis            : 'y',
       onSort : function () {

         // your code here    

            }

    });
```

The above code working fine.  Put the sub div in A and if we give a class it can be drag only with in the div